# Handling GetTickCount() overflow in timeouts

Tags: c++, integer, winapi, timeout

This is code which must run on XP, so no `GetTickCount64`, and which should correctly handle the value wrapping around after 49 days. Can it be improved?

```
// DWORD timeoutMs is a given parameter.

DWORD beginMs = (timeoutMs == INFINITE ? 0 : ::GetTickCount());
DWORD endMs = beginMs + timeoutMs; // unsigned arithmethic is Mod(MAX+1)
DWORD currentMs;

// Create Process, omitted for brevity

while ((waitResult = ::WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, DEFAULT_WAIT_MS)) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
{
    if (timeoutMs != INFINITE)
    {
        bool timeoutReached = false;
        currentMs = ::GetTickCount();
        if (beginMs <= endMs) // normal case
        {
            if (currentMs > endMs)
            {
                timeoutReached = true;
            }
        }
        else // special case: tick count wrapped around after 49 days uptime
        {
            if (currentMs < beginMs && currentMs > endMs)
            {
                timeoutReached = true;
            }
        }

        if (timeoutReached)
        {
            ::TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just have `waitResult = ::WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, timeoutMs);`? Why use `::GetTickCount()` at all?

Comment: What about the [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) functions? Are they also unavailable on XP?

Comment: @ncalmbeblpaicr0011 to be able to call a callback function in the loop and do other things like copy the standard output stream while the program is running.

Comment: @glampert They are available, that would be another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsigned subtraction (and automatic mod 2^32) will always give `currentMs - beginMs == elapsedMs`, even when `beginMs > currentMs`, and as long as the actual elapsed time doesn't overflow the tick count (it isn't greater than 49 days).

So you could replace the original with the following code:

```
DWORD beginMs = GetTickCount();

// Create Process, omitted for brevity

while ((waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, DEFAULT_WAIT_MS)) == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
    if (timeoutMs != INFINITE) {
        DWORD currentMs = GetTickCount();
        bool timeoutReached = currentMs - beginMs > timeoutMs;
        if (timeoutReached) {
            TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And you could even go a step further and eliminate the variables `currentMs` and `timeoutReached`: `if (GetTickCount() - beginMs > timeoutMs) {...`